# Android application for learning Chinese stroke characters in radicals and stroke groups

Tags: android, educational, language, accessibility, writing

There are several excellent apps for learning Chinese writing, including, [Pleco Chinese dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pleco.chinesesystem) and the [Chinese Writer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.molatra.chinesewriter) Chinese writing game.

However, it would be nice if there were an app that allowed you to learn Chinese character radicals and components (with textual descriptions of what they are, what they represent, and what they represented (perhaps also with a clickable section that shows you with drawings the evolution of the given stroke group).

Thank you for your understanding.

This app would be great for Chinese learners, educators, and brain builders, players, and helpers (and in depth understanding acquirers, including those who would want to gain a historical understanding and in depth comprehension).

Thank you for developing such an app.

Thank you for your support.

Thank you for your understanding.

Where can I find such an app?

Best regards,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use an app called [`Kanji Study`](https://mindtwisted.com/index.html) with the outliner add-on. It has a radical dictionary and shows the radicals composing a Kanji. With the add-on, you'll also see the different components of the Kanji and how it evolved over time / where it originally came from.

It is not for Chinese though but Japanese, but if you are just interested in the translation, not the pronunciation it should work for the most part I guess?